# Why is JOI more popular than AJV?

Tags: javascript, validation, jsonschema, joi, ajv

I am deciding on a validation library that I can use for both client and server side validation. I have been comparing JOI (+ joi-browser) and AJV.

As I understand it JOI and AJV can accomplish the same things. 
AJV can even perform async validation where as JOI cannot. It seems like AJV also validates the JSON schema written in the [standardized format](https://json-schema.org/) which is convenient, but it is not as developer friendly as JOI.

[JOI](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) has over twice as many stars and contributors as [AJV](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv).

Why is it that JOI is twice as popular as AJV?

Answer (score 112):

The important difference between AJV and Joi is that AJV is a JSON Schema validator and Joi is a JavaScript validator. JSON Schema is cross-platform while Joi only works in JavaScript. So, this isn't a choice between AJV and Joi as much as it's a choice between JSON Schema and Joi.

Each approach has its trade-offs, so which you choose depends a lot on your specific situation.

**AJV/JSON Schema**

The big win you get from JSON Schema is that it's cross platform. JSON Schema validator implementations exist in every major programming language. No matter what language you choose, you can use the same JSON Schema on the frontend and the backend and get consistent validation results. Write once, validate anywhere.

The downside is that because it's cross platform, it's also somewhat limited in what it can do. It's purposely kept simple enough so that it's not too difficult to implement in any programming language. Because JSON Schema isn't a full fledged programming language, it's limited in what it can do.

You might choose AJV/JSON Schema if you are using something other than JavaScript on the backend or your app is a public API that could be used by any number of apps in any number of languages.

**Joi**

Joi's biggest advantage is its usability. It's easy to use, easy to extend, and it has the full power of JavaScript.

The downside is that if you want to reuse your validation logic on the frontend *and* the backend, your only choice of language on the backend is node.

You might choose Joi if you use JavaScript for the frontend and the backend and don't anticipate non-JavaScript clients that you need to support. This is a fairly narrow situation, but if it is your situation, you will likely get more out or Joi than AJV/JSON Schema.

**Popularity**

Github stars aren't a great measure of popularity. If you look at npm daily downloads you see a very different story (AJV: 18.9M, Joi: 2.2M). JSON Schema is by far more widely used because it is cross platform. AJV is just one implementation in one language. But, if your development stack fits Joi's particular niche, it can be just as good a choice or a better choice than JSON Schema.

Comment: @Jason Thank you, very informative!  You mention AJV/JSON Schema is limited in what it can do, can you clarify what you mean by that? 

As I understand it, when validating an object against a schema you can accomplish many of the same things with AJV(JSON Schema) and Joi (converting the JSON schema into the Joi schema). Since AJV and Joi both have the ability to create a custom validators, perform conditional and nested validation, and all standard validation functionality.

Comment: @Jason Also, when you say "You might choose AJV/JSON Schema if you are using something other than JavaScript"  AJV is the JSON schema validator for Javascript so I believe that statement is misleading. I think you are referring to the ability to validate the [json schemas in any language](https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validator-javascript). Is that correct?

Comment: Re: JSON Schema limitations. AJV gets around most of these limitation with custom functionality and custom plugins, but when you use those customization features, you loose interoperability with other JSON Schema libraries and thus loose the whole point of choosing JSON Schema in the first place.

Comment: I'll give three examples of things you can't do with JSON Schema. (1) You can't compare one value against another. You can't enforce that `#/minWeight` is less than `#/maxWeight`. (2) You can't compare dates. JSON Schema only recognizes JSON types. That doesn't include dates. Dates are represented as strings. Therefore, you can't enforce a minimum or maximum date. (3) You can't reference an external source such as a database or web service. In a social media app when you add a friend to your network, you might want to enforce that the added friend actually exists in your system.

Comment: Re: "misleading statement". Sorry, that was certainly confusing. Yes, I'm referring to the ability to validate JSON Schemas in any language.